# AlarmManager can be received in other apps

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to run a task every ten minute, and i used `AlarmManager` like following:

```
public static void startAlarmOnce(Context context, String action, long triggerAtMillis) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

But, there's one problem: if someone registered a BroadcastReceiver use the same action, then he can receive the broadcast.

so, how to keep the broadcast in my own app, like LocalBroadcast do?

Answer (score 1):

Use an [explicit intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleExplicit):

```
public static void startAlarmOnce(Context context, String action, long triggerAtMillis) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

Where `YourBroadcastReceiver.class` should be the name of the class you implemented as BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I can't give an concrete `YourBroadcastReceiver` here. It was defined in my `BaseActivity`.  And if i write `BaseActivity.MyBroadcastReceiver.class`, the receiver can not receive anything.

Comment: just declare the inner class with the `static` keyword like this: `static class YourBroadcastReceiver { ... }`

Comment: I tried it. but the method `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` was never executed.